# Unable to start different Activity from launcher-type Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm stuck with an interesting problem: I have a launcher-type Activity with `Theme.NoDisplay` (no UI) which should launch different Activities depending on some conditions and even though I'm calling `startActivity()`, it won't launch any of them if the app was started via launcher icon (it does start `LauncherActivity` but then dies with no errors/exceptions).

**HOWEVER**

If I'm starting `LauncherActivity` via ADB or add a delay to `startActivity()` it seems to work just fine.

Here's a code snippet.

```
public class LauncherActivity extends Activity {

private Handler handler = new Handler();
private SharedPreferences preferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    preferences = getSharedPreferences(App.getContext().getString(R.string.preferences_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
    int pesel = preferences.getInt(App.getContext().getString(R.string.pref_pesel), 0);
    String password = preferences.getString(App.getContext().getString(R.string.pref_password), "");

    Intent intent;

    if (pesel != 0 && !password.isEmpty()) {
        // TODO: server-side password check
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    }

    Intent startIntent = getIntent();
    intent.setAction(startIntent.getAction());
    intent.setFlags(startIntent.getFlags());
    if (startIntent.getExtras() != null)
        intent.putExtras(startIntent.getExtras());

    final Intent readyIntent = intent;

    /*
    THIS DOENS"T WORK (WORKS IF STARTED VIA ADB THOUGH)
    */
    startActivity(readyIntent);

    /*
    THIS HOWEVER DOES WORK (ALWAYS)
    */
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(readyIntent);
        }
    }, 5000);

    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: show us your manifest?

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution myself.

I was following [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/11/02/psa-android-6p0-theme.nodisplay-regression.html) explaining why we should call `finish()` before `onResume()` of `Theme.NoDisplay` Activities.

To fix my issue I did something like this and it seems to work:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (isFinishing() && intent != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I don't have clear explanation why, but I'll leave it here anyways, might help someone.